Seeking Guidance: Learning Teradata and Installing Express Version
I am currently in the process of learning Teradata and I'm eager to dive deeper into the world of data management and analytics. As part of my learning journey, I am seeking guidance on how to install the Teradata Express Edition and practice using it.
I am aware that Teradata Express Edition is a free version of the Teradata Database software that can be installed locally for learning and experimentation purposes. However, I'm uncertain about the installation process and how to set it up on my machine or virtual environment.
If anyone has experience with installing and configuring Teradata Express Edition, I would greatly appreciate your assistance and insights. I am particularly interested in understanding the steps involved in setting up a local Teradata Database instance and connecting to it for practice.
Additionally, any tips, resources, or recommendations for getting started with Teradata and making the most out of the practice environment would be invaluable to me.
Thank you in advance for your help and support
I looked for Teradata Express, but it's no longer availbale.

To download and setup guidelines go to https://downloads.teradata.com/download/database/teradata-express/vmware (requires a quick registration). But the Express version is outdated. The recommended version is Clearscape Experience in the cloud, no installation required, can be accessed from your local client and comes with lots of preloaded data/examples. The only restriction is the 40hrs/per month - of course you could register anothe user :-)
